# webpack 4 and d3 es6 imports not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack4 to bundle a d3 based client application.  However when the code is bundled it produces the following error:

```
/* Cannot get final name for export "default" in "./node_modules/d3-selection/index.js" 
(known exports: , known reexports: create creator local matcher mouse namespace namespaces 
clientPoint select selectAll selection selector selectorAll style touch touches 
window event customEvent) */
undefined.select('body')
  .append('canvas')
  .attr('id', 'mycanvas')
  .attr('width', 640)
  .attr('height', 480);
```

In my source I have

```
import selection from 'd3-selection';
selection.select('body')
  .append('canvas')
  .attr('id', 'mycanvas')
  .attr('width', 640)
  .attr('height', 480);
```

I'm not sure if this is a related symptom or not but when I try `import selection as d3sel from 'd3-selection';` i get an error from webpack about not being able to pase the statement.

My package.json file looks like:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "d3-selection": "^1.3.0",
  "webpack": "^4.10.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.0.2"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps selection isn't the default export?

Try

```
import { selection } from 'd3-selection';
```

Comment: it seems d3 doesn't provide default exports from its module packs.